# Flexbox: one full width block and two with image under it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create something that looks more like this:
[image]

It must look the same for mobile devices:
one 100% block and 2 image with buttons under it.
The picture must occupy the entire width of the block.

The code below has a lot of empty space between blocks with a picture and at lower resolutions it does not work as desired.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #e2eaf4;
  padding: 10px;
          flex-direction: row;

}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background: #3794fe;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 12px;
 
}

.child:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}
.link {
background-color:white;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg"width="200" height="200" >
  <div class ="link"><a href = "#">link </a> </div>
</div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg"  width="200" height="200">
  <div class ="link"><a href = "#">link </a> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #e2eaf4;
  padding: 10px;
          flex-direction: row;

}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background: #3794fe;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  
}

.child:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}
.child:nth-child(n+2){
  width: 49%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.link {
background-color:white;
padding: 20px;
margin: 12px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" >
  <div class ="link"><a href = "#">link </a> </div>
</div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg"  ">
  <div class ="link"><a href = "#">link </a> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #e2eaf4;
  padding: 5px;
          flex-direction: row;

}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background: #3794fe;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 3px;
  
}

.child:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}
.child:nth-child(n+2){
  width: 49.9%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.link {
background-color:white;
padding: 20px;
margin: 12px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" >
  <div class ="link"><a href = "#">link </a> </div>
</div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg"  ">
  <div class ="link"><a href = "#">link </a> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the image fill the child element, you need to set its width to 100% and height to auto.

Here is the altered snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #e2eaf4;
  padding: 10px;
          flex-direction: row;

}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background: #3794fe;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  
}

.child:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}
.child:nth-child(n+2){
  width: 49%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.link {
background-color:white;
padding: 20px;
margin: 12px;
}
.container .child img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg"width="200" height="200" >
  <div class ="link"><a href = "#">link </a> </div>
</div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg"  width="200" height="200">
  <div class ="link"><a href = "#">link </a> </div>
</div>
</div>
```